# clarification about "Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License"

Tags: licensing

I need more clarification aboutCreative Commons Attribution 3.0 License[http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/]

Refer to [Creative License site](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)
What's the meaning of "Attribution — You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work"?

Thanks,
Rashidul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have give credit to the licensor if you use their work (however they specify) but you can't claim that they endorse your project (use trademarks, their names, etc.).

So if I use Library X by Dr. Y under CC3, I have to say that I am using Library X created by Dr. Y, but Dr. Y is by no means linked to this project.

If you have any more licensing questions, refer to my site http://www.tldrlegal.com/.